# camera preview blurry and zoomed in

Tags: android, gradle, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to make a preview screen with a circle overlay on top of it. Due to project requirements, the preview screen has to be large enough to fully contain the circle. The project requirements also specified that there are maximum dimensions that can never be exceeded regardless of the device due to the risk of exceeding the camera bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of garbage capture data.

In order to account for this, I basically made it so that the preview screen width will be set to the max or the width of the screen if the device isn't large enough. This got the dimensions that I wanted for the preview screen but it's very zoomed in and blurry.

I'm not sure how to both get the proper dimensions and maintain good camera quality. I would really appreciate any help in fixing this.

**Relevant code snippets**:

AutoFitTextureView.java:

```
package edu.washington.cs.ubicomplab.camera2skeleton;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.TextureView;

/**
 * A {@link TextureView} that can be adjusted to a specified aspect ratio.
 */
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be measured based on the ratio
     * calculated from the parameters. Note that the actual sizes of parameters don't matter, that
     * is, calling setAspectRatio(2, 3) and setAspectRatio(4, 6) make the same result.
     *
     * @param width  Relative horizontal size
     * @param height Relative vertical size
     */
    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

setUpCameraOutputs and chooseOptimalSize methods in Camera2Fragment.java:

```
/**
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, choose the smallest one that
     * is at least as large as the respective texture view size, and that is at most as large as the
     * respective max size, and whose aspect ratio matches with the specified value. If such size
     * doesn't exist, choose the largest one that is at most as large as the respective max size,
     * and whose aspect ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices           The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output
     *                          class
     * @param textureViewWidth  The width of the texture view relative to sensor coordinate
     * @param textureViewHeight The height of the texture view relative to sensor coordinate
     * @param maxWidth          The maximum width that can be chosen
     * @param maxHeight         The maximum height that can be chosen
     * @param aspectRatio       The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */
    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
                                          int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {

        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are smaller than the preview Surface
        List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                    option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
                if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                        option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                } else {
                    notBigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the
        // largest of those not big enough.
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

/**
     * Sets up member variables related to camera.
     *
     * @param width  The width of available size for camera preview
     * @param height The height of available size for camera preview
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
    private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                        ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                Log.d(TAG, "Screen Size: " + displaySize.x + " x " + displaySize.y);
                int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;
                int maxAllowedWidth = Math.min(displaySize.x, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH);
                int maxAllowedHeight = Math.min(displaySize.y, MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);

                if (swappedDimensions) {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Rotated Preview Size 1: " + rotatedPreviewWidth + " x " + rotatedPreviewHeight);
                Log.d(TAG, "Max Preview Size 1: " + maxPreviewWidth + " x " + maxPreviewHeight);

                double aspectRatio = (double) rotatedPreviewWidth / rotatedPreviewHeight;

                int optimalPreviewWidth = maxAllowedWidth;
                int optimalPreviewHeight = (int) (optimalPreviewWidth / aspectRatio);

                if (optimalPreviewHeight > maxAllowedHeight) {
                    optimalPreviewHeight = maxAllowedHeight;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Entered");
                    optimalPreviewWidth = (int) (optimalPreviewHeight * aspectRatio);
                }

                rotatedPreviewWidth = optimalPreviewWidth;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = optimalPreviewHeight;

                Log.d(TAG, "Rotated Preview Size 2: " + rotatedPreviewWidth + " x " + rotatedPreviewHeight);
                Log.d(TAG, "Max Preview Size 2: " + maxPreviewWidth + " x " + maxPreviewHeight);

                // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                // garbage capture data.
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxAllowedWidth,
                        maxAllowedHeight, largest);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("preview size: (%d, %d)", mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight()));

                // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }
```

fragment_camera2.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.washington.cs.ubicomplab.camera2skeleton.Camera2Fragment">

    <edu.washington.cs.ubicomplab.camera2skeleton.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="477dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.216" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ring_overlay"
        android:layout_width="460dp"
        android:layout_height="441dp"
        android:src="@drawable/colorring"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.507"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/angle0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shutter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/session_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="@string/save_session_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.703"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/photo_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagecounter_bg"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:src="@drawable/oval_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.97" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imagecounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 / 5"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imagecounter_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imagecounter_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imagecounter_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imagecounter_bg"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.507" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/review_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#414141"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/texture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_review"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="475dp"
        android:src="@drawable/angle5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/texture"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/texture" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/review_btns"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texture">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/review_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/review_retake"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:text="Retake" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```